# How can I add multiple files to an input sequentially with the number limit for input and preview?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I select several files in the first step, it selects all files and there is no problem, but if I select files again, it deletes the previous files.
How can I save the previous files by selecting the files again?

And if I select files in the first order and also select files in the second order, I will have all the files

```js
   

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  ImgUpload();
});

function ImgUpload() {
  let imgWrap = "";
  let imgArray = [];

  $('.upload__inputFile').each(function() {
    $(this).on('change', function(e) {
      imgWrap = $(this).closest('.upload__box').find('.upload__img-wrap');
      let maxLength = $(this).attr('data-max_length');
      let files = e.target.files;
      let filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
      let iterator = 0;

      filesArr.forEach(function(f, index) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
          return;
        }

        if (imgArray.length > maxLength) {
          return false
        } else {
          let len = 0;

          for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
            if (imgArray[i] !== undefined) {
              len++;
            }
          }

          if (len > maxLength) {
            return false;
          } else {
            imgArray.push(f);

            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
              let html = "<div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(" + e.target.result + ")' data-number='" + $(".upload__img-close").length + "' data-file='" + f.name + "' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></div>";
              imgWrap.append(html);
              iterator++;
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });

  $('body').on('click', ".upload__img-close", function(e) {
    let file = $(this).parent().data("file");

    for (let i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
      if (imgArray[i].name === file) {
        imgArray.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }

    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
}

$(".remove").click(function() {
  $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
});
```

```html
<div class="upload__box">
  <input type="file" id="files" name="image[]" value="" multiple data-max_length="9" class="upload__inputFile">
  <div class="upload__img-wrap"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've put your code in a demo snippet so it's easier to work with, but your question is quite broad. You're expected to make an effort and ask more specific questions. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: tip: use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using the legacy FileReader